# What does tailwind:watch do in my package.json?

Tags: tailwind-css

What does

```
"scripts": {    
   "tailwind:watch": "tailwindcss -i resources/css/main.css -o resources/css/tailwind.css --watch"
}
```

do exactly in my package.json?

it replaces/overwrites resources/css/tailwind.css but how? What do the options -i and -o do?

Comment: `npx tailwindcss --help`?

Comment: This was the direction I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx tailwindcss --help` command,to know what exactly `-i` `-o` do.

Output:

```
tailwindcss v3.2.4

Usage:
   tailwindcss [--input input.css] [--output output.css] [--watch] [options...]   
   tailwindcss init [--full] [--postcss] [options...]

Commands:
   init [options]

Options:
   -i, --input              Input file
   -o, --output             Output file
   -w, --watch              Watch for changes and rebuild as needed
   -p, --poll               Use polling instead of filesystem events when watching
       --content            Content paths to use for removing unused classes      
       --postcss            Load custom PostCSS configuration
   -m, --minify             Minify the output
   -c, --config             Path to a custom config file
       --no-autoprefixer    Disable autoprefixer
   -h, --help               Display usage information
```